# How to show datepicker calendar when the input get focus and update calendar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have a calendar example based in this URL:
http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-2 col-md-2">
    <label for="datebirth" class="control-label">Date of Birth</label>
    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date-birth" maxlength="10" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>                      
</div>
```

This is the JS code:

```
moment.locale('en', {
  week: { dow: 1 } // Monday is the first day of the week
});     

$("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
});

$("#date-birth").on("focus", function() {
    //open calendar
});
```

My calendar must be opened when do click in the calendar icon (this is ok) and when the input date has got the focus, and after, if i write a fecha in the input date field, the calendar window must be updated automatically.

In the URL , there are a example about No Icon (input field only):, but i not getting resolve it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can initialize your calendar adding `allowInputToggle` option, in order to make it open also when the input gains focus:

```
$("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    allowInputToggle: true
});
```

You can also add `useCurrent: false` if you want to have an empty input when the calendar opens for the first time.

You can use a `keyup` listner to update the calendar automatically when you type a date:

```
$("#date-birth").on("keyup", function() {
    var dt = moment(this.value, 'DD/MM/YYYY', true);
    if( dt.isValid() ){
        $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").date(dt);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to change in your css for datetimepicker. just add one line like below

FROM

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget {
  list-style: none;
}
```

TO

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
}
```